# Android Networkonmainthreadexception even though it's in a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

I can't post all the code here because I've tried it a zillion ways.  Let me preface it by saying I've used threads (usually Thread class but sometimes Runnable) lots of times in Android with no problem.

In this situation, I'm trying to make a socket connection, and I know network operations have to be done in threads.  However, whether I use a Thread class, a Runnable, an AsyncTask, or whatever (haven't tried callable yet), and the thread gets created and executed, when it hits the line to make a new socket connection it immediately throws a NetworkOnMainThreadException, even though it's in a thread, and (in the last try) an AsyncTask at that.  What am I missing that would make it happy?

Comment: By any chance did you call `run()` on the thread object instead of `start()`? And see the exception stacktrace to see where exactly the offending network call is.

Comment: No, I called Start.  I'm still reshuffling things around.  Walking with the debugger the socket call takes me direct to exception.  Where it is in the socket call, don't know yet.

Comment: Please include code and exception stacktrace to get any help here.